# Error with code=exited, status=2 when starting VNC

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, centos, cloud, vnc

I have problem when starting VNC it giving error looks like this :

```
Job for vncserver@:1.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status vncserver@:1.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

when i check the status the error looks like this :

```
vncserver@:1.service - Remote desktop service (VNC)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@:1.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-05-07 07:43:11 UTC; 10s ago
  Process: 2442 ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver %I (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 2436 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || : (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 07 07:43:11 dev-srv-nlr systemd[1]: Starting Remote desktop service (VNC)...
May 07 07:43:11 dev-srv-nlr systemd[1]: vncserver@:1.service: control process exited, code=exited status=2
May 07 07:43:11 dev-srv-nlr systemd[1]: Failed to start Remote desktop service (VNC).
May 07 07:43:11 dev-srv-nlr systemd[1]: Unit vncserver@:1.service entered failed state.
May 07 07:43:11 dev-srv-nlr systemd[1]: vncserver@:1.service failed.
```

do you know how to solve this ? Thanks in advance.